# how to push element into array inside array in mongodb while updating the sibling field of parent array in document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

Hell devs, Here is my document schema

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var botSchema = new Schema({
Bot_name: String,
UserName:String,
Modules: [{
    ModuleStatement: String,
    ModuleID: String,
    ModuleResponse: [{

        Response: String,
        TransBotID: String
    }]
}]
});
```

what i want to do is update the ModuleStatement as well as push the element into ModuleResponse setting Response and TransBotID to some values

I tried following but it only updates the ModuleStatement and doesn't push element into ModuleResponse

```
   botSchema.update({ 'Modules.ModuleID': req.body.ModId }, { '$set': { 'Modules.$.ModuleStatement': req.body.Statement } }, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            } else {


                botSchema.update({ "Modules.ModuleID": req.body.ModId }, { "$push": { "ModuleResponse": { "Response": req.body.Statement, "TransBotID": req.body.transitmod } } }, function (err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
                    else {
                        res.json('upgraded');
                    }
                })

            }
        })
```

how can i push element into ModuleResponse while setting the ModuleStatement at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

`$push` is only available in the `$group` stage. You may want to try as the following:

```
botSchema.find({'Modules.ModuleID': req.body.ModId}, (err, bots) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        bots.forEach((bot) => {
            bot.modules.forEach((botModule) => {
                if (botModule.ModuleID == req.body.ModId) {
                    botModule.Statement = req.body.Statement;
                    botModule.ModuleResponse.push({
                        Response: req.body.Statement,
                        TransBotID: req.body.transitmod
                    })
                }
            });
            bot.save((err, data) => {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        });
        res.json('upgraded');
    }
})
```

Comment: As for `$push` your statement applies only in Aggregation Framework. During updates you are free to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a shell code:

```
db.bot.update(
    { "Modules.ModuleID": "<some_id>" },
    {
        "$set": { "Modules.$.ModuleStatement": "<some_statement>" },
        "$push": {
            "Modules.$.ModuleResponse": {
                "Response" : "<some_response>", 
                "TransBotID" : "<some_trans_id>"
            }
        }
    }
)
```

The thing is that you [can](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-parameter) have more than one update expressions in one update document. I believe you can convert it to mongoose quite easily.